# Como deletar um commit antigo do Git?

Tags: git, github, commit, repository

galera, anteriormente eu estava jogando algumas coisas no git e sem querer copiei uma pasta com um arquivo dentro e commitei localmente, depois eu exclui ele e commitei a exclusão localmente, fui desenvolvendo o que eu precisava e comittando, quando fui dar um push pra o remoto, o repositório ta reclamando do arquivo existente no primeiro commit, como faço para "excluir" esse commit bichado?

Comment: Podes fazer `git reset --soft HEAD^1`, indo removendo commits até esse que não queres (caso ainda não tenhas commits no remote).

Comment: Reclamando como? Qual foi a mensagem?

Comment: ele reclama do tamanho do arquivo passou 140mb(que é justamente o arquivo que joguei sem querer em um commit), ai agora eu queria arranjar alguma forma de excluir esse commit para poder realizar o push pro repo remoto

Comment: eu ja tenho commit no remoto, nunca fiz um rebase, da algum problema?

Answer (score 3):

Se o commit que introduziu o arquivo se chama <ruim> (localiza-o com um `git log --stat`), reconstrua seu historico a partir do commit antes de <ruim> (suponho que você esta no ramo que introduzio o commit ruim):

```
git rebase -i <ruim>~1
```

Um arquivo texto va aparecer num editor de arquivo. Ele lista todos os commits que usar para refazer histórico (um rebase interativo) a partir do commit ruim (primeira linha). Tem que decidir o que fazer. 2 possibilidades:

1- O commit <ruim> contem só a introdução do mau arquivo (e nada outro). Só tem que excluir a linha com o commit ruim no arquivo. Salva o arquivo, fecha o editor, deixe o historico se fazer de novo sem o mau commit e `git push` no fim.

2 - O commit <ruim> contem a introdução do mau arquivo e outras coisas que você quer conversar. Substitua a linha do commit assim:

```
pick <ruim> Mensagem do commit
```

em:

```
edit <ruim> Mensagem do commit
```

Salva o arquivo e fecha ele. O git vá refazer o histórico parando depois do mau commit. Espera ate a pausa no rebase, e:

```
git reset HEAD~1 # cancelar commit ruim
git status # ver que arquivos introduzir no commit
git add <arquivos que conservar>
...
rm <mau arquivo>
git commit -m "Mensagem do commit" # refazer commit
git rebase --continue # aplicar os commits seguintes se tem mais no rebase
git push
```

Comment: cara sou nunca fiz um rebase, fiquei meio perdido na sua explicação kkk

Comment: Adicionei informações no post. Diga se você entende agora. Se você precisa, eu vou adicionar um outro jeito para resolver o seu problema.